# How do I access the data from my domain service in my view model ? Silverlight 5 application

Tags: c#, silverlight, domain-service-class, domaincontext

I am a beginner in Silverlight and I just started to get used to it, but now I have a problem. In my StudentDomainService I have this method that returns all of my students:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return _studentService.GetStudents();
    }
```

StudentService is a class from the business part of my application (I have a project and I have to follow some requirements, one of them is to have the business solution that contains StudentModel, StudentRepository and StudentService).
In the .web solution I have the StudentDomainService that has access to my StudentService class.
The problem is that in the View Model I have this method:

```
 public void LoadStudents()
    {
       _studentDomainContext.GetStudents();
    }
```

But obviously this is wrong because it does absolutely nothing and I know the problem is that I don't use the domain contex in the right way, but I don't know how to fix this and I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to do this correctly.
Thank you!

Comment: Whether WPF, UWP or Silverlight, the *View* uses data binding to bind to the ViewModel's properties. That means the results of `GetStudents` should be stored in a `Students` property whose setter raises the PropertyChanged event. That will signal the view it needs to reload the students

Answer (score 1):

Have a local member to store the value.

```
private List<Student> students;

//...

public void LoadStudents() {
    // get data
    var data = _studentDomainContext.GetStudents();
    students = data.ToList();

    //...
}
```

From there it is up to you how you want to expose or use that value.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for, I only have one problem, I can't access the ToList() method even though I have using System.Linq in my project ...

Comment: @Ioana confirm what type `_studentDomainContext.GetStudents()` returns to verify that we can call the linq extension on it.

Comment: it returns IEnumerable<Student>

Comment: @Ioana ok then it should be able to use the `ToList()`. If all else fails you can create the list manually by enumerating it using `foreach`